# Redirect from Django Login page to another page and then to the admin page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

Is it possible to redirect the user who successfully logged to a custom page. And if it is can I create a button with it the user gets redirected to the normal admin page ? It would look like this:

Login page [Login successfully]> Custom page [continueButton]> Admin page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can customize your view on POST and create a redirect there.

It would look something like:

```
    from django.shortcuts import redirect

    def my_view(request):
    ...
    if request.method="POST":
    ...
      return redirect('URL' or 'viewname')
```

Do the same on both pages

Comment: hm yeah I already knew how to redirect. But I need to know the path to the login and admin html pages :/ Do you know where I can find those ?

Comment: Use {% url 'admin:index' %} for the admin home

Comment: For the login page - just use the LOGIN_URL const to get to it. Look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url

Comment: You can override the default login screen to yours so it redirects to where you want